# How to prevent AppDomain recycles in IIS 7.0 when deleting a sub directory?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008, appdomain

I have an ASP.Net web application that allows users to upload files to an `uploads` directory that is located in the same virtual directory as the web app. Each uploaded file goes into a temporary sub directory that is named after the user's session id. Once I am finished with the files, I delete the temp sub directory. The only problem is that when a sub directory is deleted, the `AppDomain` gets recycled and kills all user sessions (using `inproc` session state). The culprit appears to be a `FileChangesMonitor` that watches for changes in all sub directories in the application.

The following code works great in IIS 6.0 running on Windows Server 2003 to disable the `FileChangesMonitor` for sub directories, but for some reason it's not working in IIS 7.0 on Windows Server 2008:

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo p = typeof(System.Web.HttpRuntime).GetProperty("FileChangesMonitor", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
object o = p.GetValue(null, null);
System.Reflection.FieldInfo f = o.GetType().GetField("_dirMonSubdirs", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
object monitor = f.GetValue(o);
System.Reflection.MethodInfo m = monitor.GetType().GetMethod("StopMonitoring", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic); 
m.Invoke(monitor, new object[] { });
```

I found another solution that disables the `FileChangesMonitor` altogether [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613824/how-to-prevent-an-asp-net-application-restarting-when-the-web-config-is-modified/629876#629876). But this is not the ideal solution as I still want to monitor all other files except for the temp sub directories in the `uploads` directory.

Why does this work in IIS 6.0 and not in IIS 7.0?

In IIS 7.0 can you specify sub directories in a virtual folder you want to disable recycling on?

Is there another way to do this without using reflection?

Comment: Is there some reason that the Upload folder cannot be outside the webroot?

Comment: The uploads folder is mainly for images, I want to be able to display the images to the user before they get deleted.

Comment: You could put the uploads folder outside the webroot and create a virtual directory inside the application that points to it. I'm not sure if that will prevent recycles or not. You could also stream images (just create an ASPX page or a handler that reads from the uploads folder) from outside the webroot.

Answer (score 2):

@fyjham is right, you need to move your upload folder outside the `webroot`. If this is a public-facing site, having it under the `webroo`t is a security risk to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I played around with IIS 7.0 and found out that when the managed pipeline mode was set to 'Integrated' on the application pool, the above reflection code did not work. Make sure to set your application pool's managed pipeline mode to 'Classic' instead.

There also appears no way to disable this manually through IIS either.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. However, I found the StopMonitoring changes worked for me whether or not I use Integrated or Classic pipeline. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248825/asp-net-restarts-when-a-folder-is-created-renamed-or-deleted