# asp.net: slow debugging - always fire application_start

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I have an app with about 200 aspx pages and it started to run slowly some days ago.

It seems that the VS 2010 debugger started to fire application_start on every single code change.

Before this slow behavior, the debuger fire the application_start just once and I had to stop the dev server to force the event.

- Windows 2008 R2 server x64
- Visual Studio 2010
- 3 developers via rdp (all with the same issue)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

That is how `Application_Start` is supposed to work. It only fires when the Application Pool starts or when there's a change to the code-base, or a web.config file, which would cause it to restart.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) discusses the topic in more detail.

Comment: I think it fires, when an application pool starts, which is not the same as the web-server. And in fact it should fire, when code changes.

Comment: @Xander, reading the article you posted now I think the application_start is because any code change make a full rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is either creating/ deleting folder on web server which is causing the issue.

You should check [ASP.NET restarts when a folder is created, renamed or deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248825/asp-net-restarts-when-a-folder-is-created-renamed-or-deleted)