# "Wake up" on ASP.NET web site running IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, iis

hope someone can help.

I've got a website running on a Windows Server 2008 SP2 and IIS 6.

If the site is accessed and then left for a few minutes, maybe ten to twenty, then re-accessed it can take a while to "wake up" again.  We're talking up to a minute whereas the page load time should be a second or two.  It's an intermittent issue too, but fairly easily reproducable.

I'm certain that it's not the application pool timeout that's to blame.  It's set to 180 minutes and to recycle in the early morning, and the site is *very* busy.  It's simply never idle during the day.

The session state and forms timeouts are set to 60 minutes and when the site does respond the user is still logged in, so I'm sure that it's neither of these either.

Can anyone suggest where I might look next?

Thanks - David

Comment: Are you handling / modifying / changing folders under the wwwroot ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248825/asp-net-restarts-when-a-folder-is-created-renamed-or-deleted

Comment: Maybe to other sites hosted on the same box, but to this one - absolutely not.  Updates are done outside normal working hours via a continuous integration process.  Every web site has its own app pool as well.