# Does RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue read every time from cfg file?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, iis

The azure role setting, is very useful since it lets you change values on-the-fly while **IIS** is running. But the problem is, if you have plenty users, and if it reads every time the config value from file, it is not best practice to use it without putting it in a static variable. The next problem, if you put it in a **static variable**, then you have to reset **IIS** every time you change it. I did some research, and found similar question on **stackoverflow**, which tells that only first time reads conf on file, then it stores it on cache. But that question which was answered was for **ConfigurationManager**, mine is about **RoleManager** from **Azure**.

This is the line which gets the current setting on **azure**:

```
RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Appname.settingKey");
```

This is the one that saves it in cache, which I know how it works, and gets current setting ex.: **connectionstring** in **webconfig**:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SettingKey"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Can you share the link to the Stack Overflow question you mentioned above?

Comment: yes, sure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357765/does-configurationmanager-appsettingskey-read-from-the-web-config-file-each-ti

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changed.aspx
Here is the link for changed.

If you follow the types down you can get to:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironmentchange.aspx

which is the type sent to the Changed event for changes in general.

Specifically here is the configuration value update:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironmentconfigurationsettingchange.aspx

This lists the settings that were changed.  Note that it does NOT include the values that changed, just the names of the settings, this is because the Changed event also resets the configuration cache so you read from it again since the changes happened.

Comment: This doesn't answer whether `RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue` caches or not. Does it?

Answer (score -1):

It won't read configuration every time you request the value. The configuration values will be refreshed on RoleEnvironment.Changed events.

Comment: Please can you explain, does it save as well on cache, or an url from microsoft, how can I trust you?

Comment: Actually, it's the very basic of building loaded systems and I can bet that rather smart guys code for Azure :) I didn't find complete proof, but here's  [java sources for azure sdk](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.microsoft.windowsazure/microsoft-windowsazure-api/0.1.0/com/microsoft/windowsazure/serviceruntime/RoleEnvironment.java#RoleEnvironment.0currentEnvironmentData) and variables are cached. .net code should be similar.

Comment: I Decompiled the dll that does this job, but couldn't figure out what I was interested for. I think programmers from Azure wouldn't do such mistake as well, but for a production application, a double-check never hurts anyone lol.