# Reload root web.config without restaring IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, iis-7.5, partial-trust

My app is being moved from a server running IIS6 to a server running IIS7.5.

The new server defaults to Medium Trust. As this is a shared server and I am consuming some third-party assemblies, I don't want to ask to run my app under Full Trust.

I have copied `web_mediumtrust.config` to `mycustom_mediumtrust.config`.

I have added this second line to the root `web.config` but the new `MyCustom` trust level remains unavailable.

```
<trustLevel name="High" policyFile="web_hightrust.config" />
<trustLevel name="MyCustom" policyFile="mycustom_mediumtrust.config" />
<trustLevel name="Medium" policyFile="web_mediumtrust.config" />
```

Is there a way to force a reload of the root `web.config` **without** restarting IIS and all the other apps?

Comment: I have tried recycling the application pool, no change.

Comment: possible duplicate to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613824/how-to-prevent-an-asp-net-application-restarting-when-the-web-config-is-modified

Comment: The difference is when you change an app's web.config, the restart is subtle, existing requests are finished on the current instance whilst new requests are handled by a new instance. I need to trigger a root web.config reload (the file in "%windir"\Microsoft .Net Framework\v4" etc), without killing existing requests.