# Update current web.config on-line

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, appsettings, webconfigurationmanager

I've created a screen on my web application that will allow super administrators change values of parameters on Web.Config.

**The problem**

One time we change the values of parameters using that code users connected to the applications have to refreshed it!  I would like to know if that's a good idea  >

**The code:**

```
public void SetAppSettings(string key, string value)
    {
        Configuration objConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        objConfig.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
        objConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full )
    }
```

Why the application is KO changing web.config.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613824/how-to-prevent-an-asp-net-application-restarting-when-the-web-config-is-modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when web.config is changed it forces the application to recycle. This resets the session and cache objects. If a user is in the middle of something then it can be lost.

Comment: Okey Ty James -.-' bad news for me heheeh !!