# C# - Error: Collection is read-only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to creating a custom settings system for an administration and moderator panel that changes things like the site name, description, and so on. The method I'm using now is the NameValueCollection class that allows me to get the values of my defined keys within my Web.Config file to display in their proper places. My problem is, when it comes down to changing these values, I get *Collection is read-only.*.... Heres a small snippet of the ActionResult in using to update the values and the definitions listed in my config.

```
    Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");

    NameValueCollection settings = new NameValueCollection();
    settings = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("settings");

    settings.Set("siteName", SiteName);
    settings.Set("siteDesc", SiteDesc);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");

<section name="settings" type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  <settings>
    <add key="siteName" value="Gizmo" />
    <add key="siteDesc" value="Welcome to a Gizmo Powered Website." />
  </settings>
```

Once it goes to settings.Set(); thats where the error begins. Is there anyway I get around this? Like an alternative way of updating the keys and values in my Web.Config?

Comment: in your example i don't see where you use your `config`, so you can remove it from this example

Comment: Are you trying to change the web.config of the same site where your code is running?

Comment: Look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719928/how-do-you-modify-the-web-config-appsettings-at-runtime). You can get some ideas from it.

Comment: Change your own web.congig will make your app to be restarted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613824/how-to-prevent-an-asp-net-application-restarting-when-the-web-config-is-modified

Comment: @giacomelli, If thats the case, is there a way I can make some custom config file like Web.config to do whats needed??

Comment: Yes, you can use your won settings repository (xml file, database, etc) or try to use ConfigurationManager's Save method to create a separated config file (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you are creating instance of `NameValueCollection` and then immediately rewriting it. Secondly you are not using config variable. Thirdly use `NameValueCollection.Remove()` and `Add()` methods. It should do the trick...

See following example (it's very very similar to what you want to do)

```
        Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        string key = "asd";
        var origValue = config.AppSettings.Settings[key];
        string newValue = origValue.Value + "changed";
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(key);
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, newValue);
```

(And yes - every time you rewrite the web.config the application gets restarted.)

Comment: So asp would be <add key="asd"> ?

Comment: Yeah, my testing web.config looked like this: 
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="asd" value="dsa" />
  </appSettings> </configuration>

Comment: Thanks man major major thanks!!!!! But check this out, Im working on project for web technology, if your willing to join id could use a hand!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help :) Thanks for the offer but I think I'm too busy at the moment. Have you heard about Kentico CMS? It could save you lot of time developing web solutions. ;)

Comment: No probs man I understand and actually i havent :o! Think im gonna chec into it now!