# DisallowRotationOnConfigChange setting does not appear to apply

Tags: asp.net, iis, configuration, web-config

We have a ASP.NET application running on iis7 with the application pool having "Disable Recycling for Configuration Changes" set to True.

When we make a modification to the web.config however, the app pool still recycles as indicated by the event log:

```
Event code: 1002
```

Event message: Application is shutting down. Reason: Configuration changed. 
Event time: 4/16/2015 2:34:23 PM 
Event time (UTC): 4/16/2015 9:34:23 PM 
Event ID: 36792e5493444e7893665e66e4a4415b 
Event sequence: 150 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 50004

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/edudemov9-15-130736932997750186 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /edudemov9 
    Application Path: S:\Sites\edudemov9\site\ 
    Machine name: TEHKYLE

Process information: 
    Process ID: 8820 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Is there any other setting or feature that would override the DisallowRotationOnConfigChange setting?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/315652/iis7-5-prevent-recycling-when-changing-default-document

"disallowRotationOnConfigChange is for app pool settings only and not for web.config, so an appdomain recycle still occurs even if disallowRotationOnConfigChange is applied. There is a File Change Notification (FCN) registry change that can prevent web.config changes from causing an appdomain recycle, but then the changes themselves won't be picked up either until the app pool is manually recycled..."