# Override machine.config's config section in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, system.web, machine.config

I have an MVC web app(.net framework 4.8) and I want to update the sessionState element(child element of system.web) dynamically in Web.config .
I am using an external config file for the sessionState element and updating this file dynamically. eg:

```
<sessionState configSource="Configs\SessionState.config" />
```

The config file is getting updated as expected but the app is getting restarted due to this.
I am trying to avoid the app restart here. I am trying to achieve that using **restartOnExternalChanges** property of sessionState section.
Is there any way to override the **machine.config**'s sessionState section in the web app's web.config something like(this will throw an error  "There is a duplicate 'system.web/sessionState' section defined"),

```
 <sectionGroup name="system.web" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebSectionGroup, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"> 
    <section name="sessionState" restartOnExternalChanges="false" type="System.Web.Configuration.SessionStateSection, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
 </sectionGroup>
```

The machine.config's sessionState config section looks like

```
 <sectionGroup name="system.web" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebSectionGroup, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"> 
        <section name="sessionState" type="System.Web.Configuration.SessionStateSection, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
</sectionGroup>
```

Comment: Dai, the cloud service part is not relevant, that was actually confusing, I have edited the question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Apparently (since IIS6) it is possible to make changes to the `web.config` (and other files) on-disk without triggering a restart, that's done by setting `fcnMode="disabled"` - but this doesn't mean your configuration changes will be magically re-loaded into the already-running application (they won't): you'll still need to restart it for the changes to take effect. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613824/how-to-prevent-an-asp-net-application-restarting-when-the-web-config-is-modified/629876#629876

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be editing `machine.config` - because that's systemwide CLR config and is **not** meant for storing deployment or application-specific ASP.NET settings - what you really want is `applicationHost.config`. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig

Comment: 1) ASP.NET AppDomain reload upon configuration change is by design. Like the other comment indicated, you can make some changes but the result is less likely to be what you wanted. 2) `<sectionGroup>` isn't the way to override configuration in parent files (`machine.config` or any other parent `web.config`). You won't achieve anything by doing so.