# Sessions Clearing Everytime Visual Studio is Deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens when I edit web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178342/what-happens-when-i-edit-web-config)

I have a login on my website that stores the user information into sessions. One issue however is that whenever I run or publish my applications it requires me to log in again. I test my applications frequently and I was wondering if this is common for sessions to clear everytime the application is run or published.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Take a look at this answer on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613824/how-to-prevent-an-asp-net-application-restarting-when-the-web-config-is-modified/629876#629876

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate as far as I can tell. There is a solution here specific to sessions. In that case run a session state server which is in memory but out of process and I believe won't restart when an app change occurs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you deploy new code, the application is recycled on the server. Ergo, all new sessions are created and the `application_start` methods etc in global asax are also invoked again.

If you want to 'stay logged in' regardless of session, you probably need to make some form of auto-login with a cookie on your machine.

Comment: Thank you both. I think your both correct about the issue. I just found that there are 4 methods of session state managements. By default it uses InProc, which gets clears on deployment. I think I need to change this to a different method

Answer (score 4):

When you build or deploy an application, the bin folder is updated. This causes the application to restart, so all sessions are lost.