# Is editing configuration cause iis recycle?

Tags: iis, configuration, asp.net-core, appsettings

I [saw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/178376/3202422) that in asp.net older version, editing configuration cause recycle.
(so we implemented our own library for dynamic config to avoid recycling).

Now I'm writing new asp.net core app and I have not seen anywhere that there is recycle, if using built-in configuration (like:

```
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, **reloadOnChange: true**)
```

So, can I use it without expecting any down time?

Comment: Don't force tags into the title. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging on how to properly  use tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, editing configuration does not cause IIS recycle. One of the reason maybe is that IIS is acting now merely as [a reverse proxy](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/) and the application itself runs as a separate process using the Kestrel HTTP server (if you use Kestrel).

If you need to catch moment, when configuration has been changed, you can use Configuration Reload Token  ([Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationReloadToken](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/e1b7960f22b7c508645fedb8a50f0e873d7407d5/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/ConfigurationReloadToken.cs)):

```
var config = builder.Build();
var token = config.GetReloadToken();
token.RegisterChangeCallback(_ =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Changed");
}, null);
```

But note, the token only fires once, so need have code in the callback to a change token, if needed.